# Why are two setTimeouts not in the same event loop

Tags: javascript

```
setTimeout(() => new Promise((r) => {console.log(1);r();}).then(() => console.log('1 mic')))
setTimeout(() => new Promise((r) => {console.log(2);r();}).then(() => console.log('2 mic')))
```

```
1
1 mic
2
2 mic
```

Why are two `setTimeouts` not in the same event loop

I didn't find an understandable answer after Google

Comment: My initial understanding is 
1
2
1 mic
2 mic

Comment: How could they not be in the same event loop? There is only one event loop.

Comment: Not the same round of event loop.

Comment: `setTimeout` schedules the task and starts it, when no other task is running. There is no break in the first task. Where do you see a pause in the first callback? So the first callback completely finishes before the second starts. The question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: No specific scene, just curious.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you expect `1 2 1 mic 2 mic`? It's not really clear.

Comment: Would probably help to give you a better explanation if you could explain better why you assume they should be fired in the same event loop iteration. As I state in my answer below, the simple answer is that each setTimeout will trigger a new task, and each task will be executed in its own event loop iteration (though you can have multiple callbacks of a different kind, like rAF, firing in the same iteration, but your code still wouldn't catch these.)

Comment: I am learning some scenarios of event loop.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded and scheduled tasks are only started when no other tasks are running. Maybe the promise confuses you. A promise is a tool to simplify work with asynchronous code, but a promise can also be used with synchronous code as in your code snippet.

Comment: My understanding is that their setTimeout callback time is the same, and they will be added to the event loop at the same time, that is, the same round

Comment: Well it's not how it works no, read the specs link in my answer below. Each call will schedule a new task to be queued, that means they'll all have their own iteration.

Comment: There is no "same time" in JavaScript. It's single threaded and it can't run two expressions at the same time. Your code schedules the first callback, then schedules the second callback, then runs the first callback to the end (because there is no pause) and then runs the second callback to then end.

Comment: Now I know, thank you guys.

Comment: And remember that your microtask check doesn't tell you either if your callbacks are fired in the same evnt loop or not, there is a microtask checkpoint after each callback, so even in `requestAnimationFrame(fn1); requestAnimationFrame(fn2)` you will have microtasks executed between the 2 callbacks, even though they are actually fired in the same event loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in the [Community Wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75115360/3702797), the simple reason is that [calling](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps) `setTimeout(fn)` will, after the timeout expires, [queue a new task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) to execute the callback.
So each call to `setTimeout` will queue its own task. [[Specs]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps)

But I have to note that your test wouldn't tell you if two callbacks are ran in the same event loop iteration anyway.
Indeed, every time* a callback is [invoked](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#invoke-a-callback-function), a [microtask checkpoint](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#perform-a-microtask-checkpoint) is performed in the "[cleanup after running a script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script)" algorithm.

So even in a case where we'd have multiple callbacks firing in the same event loop iteration, we'd have a microtask checkpoint in between each callback. For instance, `requestAnimationFrame()` callbacks are all fired in the same event-loop iteration, as part of the "[update the rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering)" step of the event loop. But even there, microtasks will be fired:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  console.log(1); Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(1, "micro"));
  // Try to include a new task in between
  setTimeout(() => { console.log("a new task"); });
  // block the event loop a bit so we ensure our timer should fire already
  const t1 = performance.now();
  while(performance.now() - t1 < 100) {}
});
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  console.log(2); Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2, "micro"));
});
```

So using microtasks is not a good way of checking if two callbacks are fired in the same event loop iteration. To do so, you could try to schedule a new task, like I did in that example. But even this isn't bullet proof, because browsers do have quite complex task prioritization system in place and we can't be sure when they'll fire different types of task.

The best, in supporting browsers, is to use the still under development [Prioritized task `scheduler.postTask`](https://wicg.github.io/scheduling-apis/#dom-scheduler-posttask) method. This allows us to post tasks with the highest priority, and thus we can check if two callbacks are indeed in the same event loop iteration or not. In browsers that don't support this API we have to resort to using a `MessageChannel` object which should be the closest way of post high priority tasks:

```js
const postTask = globalThis.scheduler
  ? (cb) => scheduler.postTask(cb, { priority: "user-blocking" })
  : postMessageTask;
  
const test = (fn, label) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    let sameIteration = true;
    fn(() => {
      console.log(label, "first callback");
      // If this task is executed before the next callback
      // it means both callbacks weren't executed in the same iteration
      postTask(() => sameIteration = false);
      // block the event-loop a bit between both callbacks
      const t1 = performance.now();
      while(performance.now() - t1 < 100) {}
    });
     fn(() => {
      console.log(label, "second callback");
      console.log({ label, sameIteration });
      res();
    });
  });
};
test(setTimeout, "setTimeout")
.then(() => test(requestAnimationFrame, "requestAnimationFrame") );

// If scheduler.postTask isn't available, use a MessageChannel to post high priority tasks
function postMessageTask(cb) {
  const { port1, port2 } = (postMessageTask.channel ??= new MessageChannel());
  port1.start();
  port1.addEventListener("message", () => cb(), { once: true });
  port2.postMessage("");
}
```

* <sub>That is, if the callstack is empty, which is the case most of the time, with one of the only exceptions being callbacks for events dispatched programmatically.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Because each timer callback has its own task scheduled.
[[Specs]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps)